# How do I browse the Category URL?

Tags: category, url, url-key

I am new to Magento.  Magento is installed as /products/ and I have 3 websites/stores: /products/en/ for english, /products/es/ for spanish, etc.  If I have a category URL key of 'cars', then what is the correct URL to browse the category?

I have tried:

/products/cars/

/products/en/cars/

/products/category/cars/

etc

These all return a 404 error.

I can find plenty of instructions on how to edit categories, or even programmatically find the category url, but the videos etc all leave out one important fact, how this translates to the browser URL/address!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Magento adds .html to category URLs.

So I was able to find the page at:

/products/en/cars.html

The category URL suffix is configurable.
http://www.blog.magentosupport.net/2011/07/remove-html-from-category-or-product-url-for-magento-webshop/

Answer (score 1):

This can be customized on each store (and may vary depending on the version of Magento you're running).  To verify how you have it configured on your store, log into your Magento Admin interface and go to the menu item

`Catalog -> Manage Categories`

then select the category from the list on the left.  When you do, you'll see the Category Admin Details panel display on the right of your screen.  When I do this on our `Magento 1.9.1` store, I see that the URL Key is displayed and that's the key value you're looking for :

[image: Category Display in Magento Admin]

In this example, it indicates that the URL Key is electric-breast-pumps

We have our store configured to convert the URL's generated into "HTML" pages so the final URL in this case for us is `/products/electric-breast-pumps.html` :

[image: Category List Page URL]

You can modify the configuration to not append the .HTML but it should use that by default in 1.9.X

You should be able to verify how your store is configured by viewing the Category in your Magento Admin as I demonstrate above.